# Template no me muestra el formulario realizado con ModelForm en Django

Tags: html, python, django, template

Estoy haciendo una pequeña ToDo app para empezar a practicar algunas cosas en Django y me encontré con este pequeño problema que no sé como solucionar hasta los momentos.

Estoy usando python 3 y django 1.10

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import ListView, UpdateView

from .models import Item, ItemForm

class ItemListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'items/items_list.html'
    model = Item

class ItemAdd(UpdateView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'items/item_form.html'
    form_class = ItemForm
    success_url = '/'
```

template

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import ItemListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ItemListView.as_view(), name="item"),
]
```

Todo esto solo me muestra el botton de agregar que he colocado en el template, pero nada más, tal vez estoy haciendo mal la llamada del formulario en el template, pero la verdad ni idea.

Si alguien me ayuda, lo agradeceré :P

Comment: Yo no veo ningún error, pero tengo dos observaciones: 1. No parece muy relevante en este momento, pero no hay URL en la `action` de tu formulario. 2. Podrías mostrar tu archivo `urls.py` completo (en el que llamas al formulario).

Comment: Gracias por comentar @toledano, la verdad no lo estoy llamando en la url. Estoy usando la misma url de la home, tengo que llamarla en la url de todas maneras o como?

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu archivo `urls.py`, tal vez sea importante... tal vez no.

Comment: @toledano ya esta, ahí edité

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estás llamando a la plantilla con la vista `ItemListView` pero la vista que contiene el formulario es `ItemAdd`, por eso no ves nada.

Cambia tu archivo `urls.py` la siguiente línea:

```
url(r'^$', ItemAdd.as_view(), name="item"),
```

Con eso será suficiente para que se *dibuje* el formulario, pero no hay a dónde mandarlo. Para eso tendrías que modificarlo así:

```
{% block content %}
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Toma nota de la ruta `action="/"` que recibe los datos que mandas.

Con esto podrás actualizar tu base de datos, pero recuerda que, aunque tienes una vista que muestra el contenido de tu base, no haces nada con ella.

Comment: Gracias, @toledano entonces voy a tratar de modificar más esa pequeña aplicación para ir recordando lo olvidado. Gracias :P